# How do I single side inverse selection at photoshop? I have to get inside of selected area not outside

Tags: adobe-photoshop, crop

The first image is original image.  What I want is getting inside of white border. So deleting area outside of white border. I am perfectly capable of selecting white border with magic wand tool

However if I inverse selection it selects both sides of white border so it does not achieve what I want. So somehow I have to select outside of white border somehow after I selected white border with magic wand tool.

So I can delete outside of white border then delete white border itself too so I can obtain inside of that white border. The second picture shows the white border I can select with magic wand tool so I want to extract inside of that selection

Photoshop 2014.2.1

[image: original image]

---

[image: i have to get inside of this selection somehow]

Answer (score 0):

Adjust your tolerance to 100, check the "contiguous" feature, on the magic wand and just select any spot outside of the white border.

This will achieve the desired effect, although it isn't using a "1 side of inverse" feature.

Comment: it can achieve desired effect at this particular image but it is not possible at many other images. i cant believe photoshop doesnt have this extremely basic and simple functionality . single side inverse or extract inside of selection :(

Answer (score 0):

Three clicks with the Magic Eraser, on 100%, contiguous.

[image]